# How to "manually" sort items in Digikam

Tags: file-management, digikam

Digikam includes the option to sort files in an album by "manual and name" or "manual and date." However, I haven't been able to find any way to "manually" reorder files. The official documentation doesn't seem to elaborate on this. Has anyone used this feature?

Comment: Have you try with drag and drop?

Comment: Yes, that does not work.

Answer (score 2):

I've got Version 6.4.0, and
there I was able to reorder images by dragging
after I had switched to "By Manual and name" in "View"|"Sort Items".

However, this was only possible in "Thumbnails" and "Preview" view mode,
not in "Table" view.

And I had to drag the thumbnail **onto** the thumbnail of the target position,     *not between* two thumbnails.

And the new ordering was persistent after restarting Digikam.

---

I would love to be able to persist this to disk, ie rename the files according to the displayed ordering. If anyone has got any suggestions, please do let us know.

Comment: sunito's answer works also in 7.1, but not in the most recent release 7.2. It seems there is a bug!
EDIT: it works again in the weekly snaphot digiKam-7.3.0-20210613T170955-x86-64.appimage

Comment: Edit: for renaming, check Andreas answer, way better solution. OA: You can sort the images as you do. Then create a presentation of all the images. The presentation will have the same ordering. Save the presentation. Now you can open the presentation in your favorite multi-caret (hopefully) text editor and use the file paths to create mv commands.

Answer (score 2):

Reorder the images as described above. Mark all images. Press "F2" or select menu "item", submenu "rename". A box appears with intuitive controls to rename the files. Usually, I use "number, three digits". After that, I end up with files numbered in the correct order.